# How to change thumbnails for Wordpress pages (KakaoTalk)

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

The thumbnails of all my Wordpress pages are exactly the same--an off-centered logo--when I share the links on Kakaotalk (Popular SNS in South Korea). I suspect this image comes from when I changed the wordpress login logo to a custom logo by messing with the functions.php

```
//Custom login logo

function my_login_logo() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #login h1 a, .login h1 a {
            background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/site-login-logo.png);
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

[image: thumbnails of home and about page]

I would like to change all the thumbnails to a better looking image, but all the tutorials I've found are for changing thumbnails of wordpress posts, not pages. Is there a php function that can change the thumbnails of all wordpress pages?

Comment: Do you mean the preview image for when you post on FB etc?

Comment: yeah pretty much

Comment: So it sounds like you just want to set the default featured image? Have you looked at this? https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/default-featured-image/

Comment: I just tried that and the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you applied OG tags etc?

Comment: You can use a plugin like Yoast SEO to set the images correctly. Then, when it comes to Facebook specifically, you can use the 'facebook debugger' in which you enter your site URL and it will re-crawl your site to get the fresh image

Comment: i have yoast seo and tried setting an OG tag but no dice. But using facebook debugger i managed to learn that the off-centered logo comes from the logo in my homepage rather than the login. It's actually not off-centered at all but the text next to the logo is white so I couldn't see it. If anything thanks for helping me learn about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thumbnail was coming from a png logo in my homepage. It wasn't off-centered, the text next to the black logo is white so it only looks off-centered. Thanks to ProEvilz for the tip of Facebook Debugger. I just changed the png logo to a jpg with blue background, so the thumbnail has some blue color now so I can see the white text next to the black logo